# How Can I Pop-Up Window With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, popupwindow

I am facing with a problem in ASP.NET MVC. In my project; when a city is clicked on the map, it shows the rates in the projects of that city.

That is the page:

```
@model List<tbl_Proje>

@if (Model.Any())
{
    <div class="ProjelerPartial">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="ProjePartialGovde" data-id="@item.ID">
            <div class="ProjePartialAdi">@item.Adi</div>
            <div class="ProjelerPartialDetay">
                <div class="TamamlanmaOranlari">
                    <strong>Nakdi Tamamlanma Oranı</strong>
                    <div class="TamamlanmaOranlariCubuk" style="width:@(item.NakdiTamOrani)%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="TamamlanmaOranlari">
                    <strong>Fiziki Tamamlanma Oranı</strong>
                    <div class="TamamlanmaOranlariCubuk" style="width:@(item.FizikiTamOrani)%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    </div>

<!-- Click Event -->
<script>
    $('div.ProjePartialGovde').click(function (el) {
        var projeid = $(this).data('id');
        $('.popupListe').html('içerik hazırlanıyor...');
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: '@Url.Action("ProjeOzetPartial", "Home")',
            data: { projeID: projeid,ilID:@ViewBag.ilID }
        })
            .done(function (msg) {
                $('.popupListe').html(msg);
            });
    });
</script>
}
else
{
    <text>There is no project for this city!</text>
}
```

When I click the rates, this is the code of the page where the data about the project is:

And what I want to do is: I want this window to open with pop-up.

```
@model tbl_Proje

<h2>@Model.Adi</h2>

<div>
    <a href="#" class="ProjeListesiGeri"><-- </a>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Başlangıç/Bitiş Tarihleri: @Model.SozBasTarihi / @Model.SozBitisTarihi </div>
    <div>Nakdi ve Fiziki Tamamlanma Oranları: %@Model.NakdiTamOrani / %@Model.FizikiTamOrani</div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Detay","Proje",new {ID=Model.ID })">Detayına Git</a>
</div>
<script>
    $('.ProjeListesiGeri').click(function (el) {
        $('.popupListe').html('içerik hazırlanıyor...');

        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: '@Url.Action("ProjelerListesiPartial", "Home")',
            data: { ilID: @ViewBag.ilID }
        })
            .done(function (msg) {
                $('.popupListe').html(msg);
            });
        });
</script>
```

I will add a picture for clarity:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2 (I want this window to open with pop-up.)]